# Unable to install edb on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04

I am facing the following while trying to install edb:

```
sudo apt install edb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libargtable2-0 libass5 libavcodec-ffmpeg56 libavdevice-ffmpeg56
  libavfilter-ffmpeg5 libavformat-ffmpeg56 libavresample-ffmpeg2
  libavutil-ffmpeg54 libbluray1 libboost-random1.58.0 libboost-regex1.58.0
  libboost-thread1.58.0 libcryptopp-dev libethereum libfdk-aac0 libjsoncpp1
  libjsonrpccpp-client0 libjsonrpccpp-common0 libjsonrpccpp-server0
  libleveldb1v5 libmicrohttpd10 libmicrohttpd12 libnvidia-common-396
  libopencv-core2.4v5 libopencv-imgproc2.4v5 libopenjpeg5 libpostproc-ffmpeg53
  libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libswresample-ffmpeg1
  libswscale-ffmpeg3 libtbb2 libva1 libx264-148 libx265-79 miniupnpc
  php7.1-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  emacs emacs25 emacs25-bin-common emacs25-common emacs25-el liblockfile-bin
  liblockfile1 libm17n-0 libotf0 m17n-db
Suggested packages:
  emacs25-common-non-dfsg ncurses-term m17n-docs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  edb emacs emacs25 emacs25-bin-common emacs25-common emacs25-el
  liblockfile-bin liblockfile1 libm17n-0 libotf0 m17n-db
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 34,2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 113 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 emacs25-common all 25.2+1-6 [13,1 MB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 liblockfile-bin amd64 1.14-1.1 [11,9 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 liblockfile1 amd64 1.14-1.1 [6.804 B]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 emacs25-bin-common amd64 25.2+1-6 [127 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libotf0 amd64 0.9.13-3build1 [44,6 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 m17n-db all 1.7.0-2 [1.239 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libm17n-0 amd64 1.7.0-3build1 [243 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 emacs25 amd64 25.2+1-6 [3.468 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 emacs all 47.0 [1.748 B]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 edb all 1.31-3 [360 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 emacs25-el all 25.2+1-6 [15,6 MB]
Fetched 34,2 MB in 6s (5.998 kB/s)      
Selecting previously unselected package emacs25-common.
(Reading database ... 347336 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-emacs25-common_25.2+1-6_all.deb ...
Unpacking emacs25-common (25.2+1-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblockfile-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../01-liblockfile-bin_1.14-1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblockfile-bin (1.14-1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblockfile1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-liblockfile1_1.14-1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblockfile1:amd64 (1.14-1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package emacs25-bin-common.
Preparing to unpack .../03-emacs25-bin-common_25.2+1-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking emacs25-bin-common (25.2+1-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libotf0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libotf0_0.9.13-3build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libotf0:amd64 (0.9.13-3build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package m17n-db.
Preparing to unpack .../05-m17n-db_1.7.0-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking m17n-db (1.7.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libm17n-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libm17n-0_1.7.0-3build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libm17n-0:amd64 (1.7.0-3build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package emacs25.
Preparing to unpack .../07-emacs25_25.2+1-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking emacs25 (25.2+1-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package emacs.
Preparing to unpack .../08-emacs_47.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking emacs (47.0) ...
Selecting previously unselected package edb.
Preparing to unpack .../09-edb_1.31-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking edb (1.31-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package emacs25-el.
Preparing to unpack .../10-emacs25-el_25.2+1-6_all.deb ...
Unpacking emacs25-el (25.2+1-6) ...
Setting up liblockfile-bin (1.14-1.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Setting up libotf0:amd64 (0.9.13-3build1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Setting up liblockfile1:amd64 (1.14-1.1) ...
Setting up m17n-db (1.7.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Setting up emacs25-common (25.2+1-6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libm17n-0:amd64 (1.7.0-3build1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Setting up emacs25-bin-common (25.2+1-6) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/ctags.emacs25 to provide /usr/bin/ctags (ctags) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/ebrowse.emacs25 to provide /usr/bin/ebrowse (ebrowse) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/emacsclient.emacs25 to provide /usr/bin/emacsclient (emacsclient) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/etags.emacs25 to provide /usr/bin/etags (etags) in auto mode
Setting up emacs25-el (25.2+1-6) ...
Setting up emacs25 (25.2+1-6) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/emacs25-x to provide /usr/bin/emacs (emacs) in auto mode
Install edb for emacs25
install/edb: Handling install of emacsen flavor emacs25
install/edb: Byte-Compiling in dir /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/edb/ ...
No such keyword: :indent
ERROR: install script from edb package failed
dpkg: error processing package emacs25 (--configure):
 installed emacs25 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of emacs:
 emacs depends on emacs25 | emacs25-lucid | emacs25-nox; however:
  Package emacs25 is not configured yet.
  Package emacs25-lucid is not installed.
  Package emacs25-nox is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package emacs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of edb:
 edb depends on emacs | emacs24 | emacs-snapshot; however:
  Package emacs is not configured yet.
  Package emacs24 is not installed.
  Package emacs-snapshot is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package edb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 emacs25
 emacs
 edb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Following up another on hold question ([Unable to install edb Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074326/unable-to-install-edb-ubuntu-17-10)):

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libargtable2-0 libass5 libavcodec-ffmpeg56 libavdevice-ffmpeg56
  libavfilter-ffmpeg5 libavformat-ffmpeg56 libavresample-ffmpeg2
  libavutil-ffmpeg54 libbluray1 libboost-random1.58.0 libboost-regex1.58.0
  libboost-thread1.58.0 libcryptopp-dev libethereum libfdk-aac0 libjsoncpp1
  libjsonrpccpp-client0 libjsonrpccpp-common0 libjsonrpccpp-server0
  libleveldb1v5 libmicrohttpd10 libmicrohttpd12 libnvidia-common-396
  libopencv-core2.4v5 libopencv-imgproc2.4v5 libopenjpeg5 libpostproc-ffmpeg53
  libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libswresample-ffmpeg1
  libswscale-ffmpeg3 libtbb2 libva1 libx264-148 libx265-79 miniupnpc
  php7.1-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up emacs25 (25.2+1-6) ...
Install edb for emacs25
install/edb: Handling install of emacsen flavor emacs25
install/edb: Byte-Compiling in dir /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/edb/ ...
No such keyword: :indent
ERROR: install script from edb package failed
dpkg: error processing package emacs25 (--configure):
 installed emacs25 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of emacs:
 emacs depends on emacs25 | emacs25-lucid | emacs25-nox; however:
  Package emacs25 is not configured yet.
  Package emacs25-lucid is not installed.
  Package emacs25-nox is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package emacs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of edb:
 edb depends on emacs | emacs24 | emacs-snapshot; however:
  Package emacs is not configured yet.
  Package emacs24 is not installed.
  Package emacs-snapshot is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package edb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 emacs25
 emacs
 edb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I can reproduce you issue on clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS without PPAs and any third-party repositories. So I reported [bug 1792211 to Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/edb/+bug/1792211).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was confused:

```
sudo apt install edb-debugger
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  emacs emacs25 emacs25-bin-common emacs25-common emacs25-el libargtable2-0
  libass5 libavcodec-ffmpeg56 libavdevice-ffmpeg56 libavfilter-ffmpeg5
  libavformat-ffmpeg56 libavresample-ffmpeg2 libavutil-ffmpeg54 libbluray1
  libboost-random1.58.0 libboost-regex1.58.0 libboost-thread1.58.0
  libcryptopp-dev libethereum libfdk-aac0 libjsoncpp1 libjsonrpccpp-client0
  libjsonrpccpp-common0 libjsonrpccpp-server0 libleveldb1v5 liblockfile-bin
  liblockfile1 libm17n-0 libmicrohttpd10 libmicrohttpd12 libnvidia-common-396
  libopencv-core2.4v5 libopencv-imgproc2.4v5 libopenjpeg5 libotf0
  libpostproc-ffmpeg53 libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsdl-ttf2.0-0
  libswresample-ffmpeg1 libswscale-ffmpeg3 libtbb2 libva1 libx264-148
  libx265-79 m17n-db miniupnpc php7.1-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  edb-debugger-plugins libcapstone3 libcdt5 libcgraph6 libgts-0.7-5 libgts-bin
  libgvc6 libpathplan4 libqt5concurrent5 libqt5xmlpatterns5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  edb-debugger edb-debugger-plugins libcapstone3 libcdt5 libcgraph6
  libgts-0.7-5 libgts-bin libgvc6 libpathplan4 libqt5concurrent5
  libqt5xmlpatterns5
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 3.105 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13,1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libcapstone3 amd64 3.0.4-5 [434 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libcdt5 amd64 2.40.1-2 [19,6 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libcgraph6 amd64 2.40.1-2 [40,8 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libgts-0.7-5 amd64 0.7.6+darcs121130-4 [150 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libpathplan4 amd64 2.40.1-2 [22,6 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libgvc6 amd64 2.40.1-2 [601 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libqt5xmlpatterns5 amd64 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 [916 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libqt5concurrent5 amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 [29,8 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 edb-debugger-plugins amd64 0.9.21-3 [444 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 edb-debugger amd64 0.9.21-3 [406 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libgts-bin amd64 0.7.6+darcs121130-4 [41,3 kB]
Fetched 3.105 kB in 1s (3.363 kB/s)    
Selecting previously unselected package libcapstone3:amd64.
(Reading database ... 352020 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libcapstone3_3.0.4-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcapstone3:amd64 (3.0.4-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcdt5.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libcdt5_2.40.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcdt5 (2.40.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgraph6.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libcgraph6_2.40.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcgraph6 (2.40.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgts-0.7-5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libgts-0.7-5_0.7.6+darcs121130-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgts-0.7-5:amd64 (0.7.6+darcs121130-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpathplan4.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libpathplan4_2.40.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpathplan4 (2.40.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgvc6.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libgvc6_2.40.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgvc6 (2.40.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5xmlpatterns5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libqt5xmlpatterns5_5.9.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5xmlpatterns5:amd64 (5.9.5-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5concurrent5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libqt5concurrent5_5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5concurrent5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package edb-debugger-plugins:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-edb-debugger-plugins_0.9.21-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking edb-debugger-plugins:amd64 (0.9.21-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package edb-debugger.
Preparing to unpack .../09-edb-debugger_0.9.21-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking edb-debugger (0.9.21-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgts-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libgts-bin_0.7.6+darcs121130-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgts-bin (0.7.6+darcs121130-4) ...
Setting up libgts-0.7-5:amd64 (0.7.6+darcs121130-4) ...
Setting up libpathplan4 (2.40.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Setting up libqt5xmlpatterns5:amd64 (5.9.5-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Setting up libgts-bin (0.7.6+darcs121130-4) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libcapstone3:amd64 (3.0.4-5) ...
Setting up libqt5concurrent5:amd64 (5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libcdt5 (2.40.1-2) ...
Setting up libcgraph6 (2.40.1-2) ...
Setting up edb-debugger-plugins:amd64 (0.9.21-3) ...
Setting up libgvc6 (2.40.1-2) ...
Setting up edb-debugger (0.9.21-3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

edb and edb-debugger are not the same.